# Activate the Breakpoints in UI Automation Instrument for iOS

Tags: ios-ui-automation

Is there a way of activating the Breakpoints in Xcode Instruments Automation after writing several scripts because it would seem that there are there but just inactive. I was wondering if I could debug my JS code from the Automation instruments without having the Application code in Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the breakpoint options when you right click in the gutter of the UI Automation script editor is because the whole editor pane is the code editor reused from Xcode. It's unfortunately confusing, as you've found out, but apparently that was a convenient way for them to do syntax highlighting and all that inside Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments works independently of Xcode, even if started from Xcode. If you run the Automation tool from Xcode, you will see that it starts you app and issues UI commands to it, without Xcode knowing about this: In XCode, the run button is still enabled.
This means that Xcode is not active, and breakpoints are not enabled. Thus, you cannot issue UI commands from Automation to you app so that it will stop at a breakpoint.

Comment: Actually I needed the Breakpoints in order to debug my scripts that are written in Automation instruments and i saw that when i right click on the line number i have the Breakpoint option but it is disabled and was wondering if it is possible to debug my own scripts or this features works only when i automate the App that i have in Xcode and use it in the Simulator. Thank you for the short reply